# newsletter3k, am I did something wrong, author function did not pick up author in news article

Tags: python, parsing, web, author, newspaper3k

This is about the author function of [newspaper3k](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper) Library. I have this list of URL for news. the ">>> article.authors" did not pick up authors sometimes. An example is here:[authors missing](https://www.dropbox.com/t/8c5QIfKIDrSPSy0M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Newspaper3k* uses the *Python* package *Beautiful Soup* to extract items, such as author names from a news website. The *tags* that *Newspaper3k* queries are pre-defined within *Newspaper3k* source code. *Newspaper3k* makes a best effort to extract content from these standard *tags* on a news site.

**BUT** not all news sources are structured the same, so *Newspaper3k* will miss certain content, because a tag (e.g., author) will be a different place in the HTML structure.

For instance *Newspaper3k* looks for the author name in these *tags*:

`VALS = ['author', 'byline', 'dc.creator', 'byl']`

The tag *dc.creator* is always located in the *META* tag section of a news source. If your news source has a different author tag, such as *article.author,* which the LA Times uses then you must query that tag like this:

```
article_meta_data = article.meta_data
article_author = {value for (key, value) in article_meta_data['article'].items() if key == 'author'}
```

I cover many of these harvesting issues in my [newspaper3K overview document](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview), which I have shared on my [Github page](https://github.com/johnbumgarner).

Comment: Yes, I was there:                                                                                                                                 VALS = ['author', 'byline', 'dc.creator', 'byl']                                                                     Thank you for the overview document, it is up to date, I go to read it. One spontaneous question, how about adding a tag to VALS?    There is where author located:                                                                    <p class="submitted">
                    by Nelson Daily Staff on Thursday November 19 2020        </p>

Comment: my obervation, in some webpages, the author name appears after the first "by" word (in the actual text, may not be after first "by" word in page source). I wonder if this may be the way: Finding a word after a specific word in Python using regex from text file , in stackoverflow.com

Comment: I don't control *Newspaper3k,* so I cannot modify the source code.  You have to modify your code to use *Newspaper3k* to harvest the elements correctly.  Open an issue with the *Newspaper3k* owners to add a new tag in the source code.

Comment: I also do not control the newspaper3k, I just asked such possibilites by forking in Github. I checked your wonderful examples at "  newspaper3K overview document,", please tell me where to find " bbc_dictionary.items()" and "cnn_dictionary.items() " , sorry it shows error message.

Comment: There are lready discussions about forking the package, because it hasn't been updated since 2016. Concerning "bbc_dictionary.items()" and "cnn_dictionary.items()." These items are only linked to my code example as part of my naming convention for variables being used.  I just tested my example code from my overview document that contain those variables and the examples worked with no errors.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please accept the answer. If not, please follow-up specifically so any outstanding concerns based on the original question can be addressed.

Comment: "Concerning "bbc_dictionary.items()" and "cnn_dictionary.items()." These items are only linked to my code example as part of my naming convention for variables being used.  ", Rule based system has to be very specific. This is a pain right now. the webpages I want extract authors from are not in BBC or CNN. One clue I know aobut them: author names appears after the "by" word and usually tailed by publication date.

Comment: All my code example in the [overview document](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview) can be easily modified to fit your needs.

Comment: Please accept this answer, because it has all the details needed to handle your original use case.

Comment: The code in above Answer1 works by giving me the website address of the author in LA times: 'https://www.latimes.com/people/john-myers'  when I tried on this weblink: https://www.latimes.com/california/story/2021-02-09/california-deal-over-teacher-vaccines-could-reopen-elementary-schools, I think I should use re package to extract the last part in "https://www.latimes.com/people/john-myers"

Comment: My other answer showed how to extract that part of the author URL.

Comment: Oww, I didn't notice that sorry. But I did the following and it worked:                  import re
url='https://www.latimes.com/california/story/2021-02-09/california-deal-over-teacher-vaccines-could-reopen-elementary-schools '
article = Article(url.strip(), config=config)
article.download()
article.parse()          
article_meta_data = article.meta_data
authorURL = {value for (key, value) in article_meta_data['article'].items() if key == 'author'}
string=repr(authorURL)
author= re.sub('{}', '', string)
article_author=re.sub(r'^.+/([^/]+)}$', r'\1', author)
print(article_author)

Comment: @tursunWali no worries.  I will be adding another section to my overview document related to your questions.  Please accept this answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Already accepted, appreciate your help. Love Stackoverlfow spirit

Comment: Unfortunately not everyone has the same spirit to help others and share their knowledge.  Please let me know If you have any more questions about Newspaper3k. Happy coding.

Comment: if you say so, I would say, let's improve newsletter3k, please!

Comment: here is the discussion on maintenance and forking the project: 
 https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/issues/813

Comment: Yes, just now visited there and expressed my interest, also urge those cool guys to start early.

Comment: Life is complex, could you have a look to my new post: find author name in the visible text after the first “by” word, please!